# form validation wont submit after validating

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form that requires a radio button be selected before the form can be submitted. The problem is that after selection of a radio button, the form will not submit.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma376/1/)

```
function ValidateForm(form) {
    ErrorText = "";
    if ((form.job_status[0].checked === false) && (form.job_status[1].checked === false)) {
        alert("Before you can get a signature you must mark a selection.\n Is the work completed or do you need to return?");
        return false;
    }
    if (ErrorText = "") {
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing a comparison, but an assignment in your if-condition. It will evaluate to the empty string, which is falsy, and the submit will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` instead of `=`

```
if (ErrorText == "") {
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: did you got the problem now

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
if (ErrorText = "") {
    form.submit();
}
```

needs to be this:

```
 if (ErrorText == "") {
    alert("submitted succesfully");
    form.submit();
}
```

if you miss out the second `=` then it is not working as a comparison operator, which is required to give a `true` result for the `if` statement, and then allows the submission.

Comment: the `alert` is just for you to see that it has cleared the `if`.

Comment: great, please accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left.